# Is there any way to delete some elements from a given ArrayList after adding the same elements to a new ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8, java-stream

For example, there is a list of elements. 
We call the streamMethod on this list. Now we want to extract a certain element from the list by a condition and add it to a new list.

**Example:**

```
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        intList.add(i);
}

public static List<Integer> getIntFive(List<Integer> list) {
    return list.stream().filter(i -> i.equals(5)).collect(Collectors.toList());

}

public static List<Integer> getIntEight(List<Integer> list) {
    return list.stream().filter(i -> i.equals(8)).collect(Collectors.toList());

}
```

Is there a way to delete the items added to the new list from the original list? Could one link another stream behind the first one and thus influence the property of the original list?

Comment: You can't remove while your streaming, but you could use List.remove(Object)

Comment: what you wanna do exactly ? can you show some input and output example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closer to your current implementation, another way to perform the operation would be:

```
public static List<Integer> getIntEight(List<Integer> list) {
    List<Integer> res = list.stream()
            .filter(i -> i.equals(8))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    list.removeAll(res);
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't remove while streaming, but there is no harm in iterating twice, for example:

```
    List<Integer> initial = new ArrayList<>(List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();

    initial.forEach(x -> {
        if (x > 3) {
            result.add(x);
        }
    });

    // or simply : initial.removeAll(result);
    initial.removeIf(result::contains);

    System.out.println(initial); // 1,2,3
    System.out.println(result); // 4,5
```